# TestNG Report- Publishing tests in an Order

Tags: java, selenium, testng

*TestNG Report - Publishing tests in an Order.*

How to show test in the executed order in TestNG custom report. Right now my executed tests are published randomly in TestNG report. I am using the below custom Listener code from [this URL](https://www.dev2qa.com/testng-reporting-customization/).

The TestNG XML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Main Suite" parallel="false">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.dev2qa.example.testng.report.custom.CustomTestNGReporter"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="CHApp Android Automation" preserve-order="true" enabled="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.ch.chapp.CHAppAndroidTestSuite.TestSet1">
        <methods>
          <include name="exe_Scheduler"/>
          <include name="chApp_SignIn"/>
          <include name="chApp_VerifyUserRecogInApp"/>
          <include name="chApp_HeaderMenu"/>
          <include name="chApp_HamburgerMenu"/>
          <include name="chApp_DailyPrize"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
      <class name="com.ch.chapp.CHAppAndroidTestSuite.TestSet3">
        <methods>
          <include name="c1_SuperPrizeSweep1"/>
          <include name="c1_SuperPrizeSweep1_Complete"/>
          <include name="c1_Mission1Sweep2"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
      <class name="com.ch.chapp.CHAppAndroidTestSuite.TestSet2">
        <methods>
          <include name="c1_Mission1Sweep2_Complete"/>
          <include name="chApp_VerifyVIPInApp"/>
          <include name="chApp_SignOut"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Please share any single class with @Test methods

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/197QGWtK5LThR4O6gqncIgjtkt2mmRqFT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please refer above link for the test class.

Comment: You have issue with TestNG Report or TestNG execution on @Test ?

Comment: I have issue in TestNG report, i don't see test results in the order of execution. Infant i am seeing @test result published randomly in the report. Order of execution is as expected but they show up in different order in the Custom TestNG report.

Comment: Any update, let me know if you need more details?

Answer (score 1):

- Extent Report always manage Test order as according to what you have created for it.
- There is no need to manage method name in your TestNG.XML, You should remove it. Try to create simple structure. Then implement it for your project. You should implement multiple Test without using Selenium reference, You can test it.

  Reference1 : http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#basic-usage 
    Reference2 : https://github.com/ishah09/ExtentReport-3.1.5
- You are managing inappropriately that is causing you. I found something,  ExtentManager.getExtent(); that is something different from actual usage.

So I suggest you to go through with above mentioned references and implement it.

Comment: In Extent report I have no issues and i am seeing Test results published in order of execution as well. Now only issue is TestNG. You said "There is no need to manage method name in your TestNG.XML"  this means you are asking me to remove all method names from testNG XML and remain just the class name? Really appreciate if you can give simple structure of TestNGXML.

Comment: Yes. Just needed class name only. This is my perfect example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719098/9405154