# Create TestNG xml in Intellij

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

How to create TestNG.xml in Intellij Idea

This is my test code

```
import com.applitools.eyes.RectangleSize;
import com.applitools.eyes.selenium.Eyes;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class mas1 {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://demo.applitools.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

I tried to create TestNG.xml following the below link

[TestNG with IntelliJ IDEA: How to use the testng.xml file in IntelliJ IDEA 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970214/testng-with-intellij-idea-how-to-use-the-testng-xml-file-in-intellij-idea-9)

Can somebody explain to me how to create TestNG.xml

I don't know what i have to insert in suite field and package name to create it manually.

Below is image for my directory browsing, there are no packages

[image]

Comment: There are several tutorials available that will tell you how to create it. Learning TestNG is quite easy, you will just have to spend a couple of hours max. [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html) [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sample XML for your Project,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="java.mas1"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: really thank you when i delete `<class name="java.mas1"/> `here i change like this` <class name="mas1"/> `  then only its work

Comment: Its good that, without package name also it worked. Package name helpful with easy identification, when you have large number of test. Here I mentioned java as your package name. Can you update your package name and check with it., packagename.classname is what we execute in ours code as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to this link and click install to IDE button - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9556-create-testng-xml

[image: Install the plugin to the IDE]

2. Right click on the parent project and click create TestNG XML

[image: Create TestNG XML file]